# Get woocommerce categories thumbnails for each category on category pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem. I use a filter with thumbnails. At least this filter does not include get category thumbnail and you have to upload all thumbnails manually into the filter which is not a good solution.

What I try to do is to get the thumbnail automatically from the category thumbnail. So far I have a code which adds a thumbnail from the current query which is also not a good solution. I need to get the thumbnail for each category separately.

This code works with current query and display the same image for all categories from the current opened category. Do you have any idea how could I get thumbnail for each category separately?

```
if ( is_product_category() ){
    global $wp_query;

    // get the query object
    $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

    // get the thumbnail id using the queried category term_id
    $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 

    // get the image URL
    $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 


                        return '<span class="prdctfltr_customize_block prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_image"><img src="' . $image . '" alt="' . $cat->name . '"/></span>' . ( $cnt !== false ? ' <span class="prdctfltr_customize_count">' . absint( $cnt ) . '</span>' : '' ) . ( $tip !== false ? '<span class="prdctfltr_tooltip"><span>' . wp_kses_post( $tip ) . '</span></span>' : '' ) . ( $checked !== '' ? '<input type="checkbox" value="' . esc_attr( $term_slug ) . '"' . esc_html( $checked ) . '/>' : '' ) . '<span class="prdctfltr_customization_search">' . esc_html( $term_name ) . '</span>' . wp_kses_post( $sublevel ) . '</span>';
                    }
```

[image]

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE
[PHP CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/8wmv7o6q/)

Comment: Just to clarify, you need all of your product categories thumbnails?

Comment: Yes, Im using the ajax filter which supports only category names. I want to add the category thumbnails to these filter. As Ive mentioned above so far I have the current query which is working good, but thats not the right solution. I need to get the thumbnails from wp admin categories for each category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: The following snippet has been fully tested on wordpress `5.8` and woocommerce `5.2` and it works for the default woocommerce product categories. If you're trying to use it in third party plugins, you may encounter some discrepancies. Therefore, feel free to customize it as you see fit!

If i understood you correctly, you need all of your product categories thumbnails.

You could get the all of your products categories by using `get_terms`. Then use a `foreach` loop to output your thumbnails. Like so:

```php
$args = array(
  'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
  'hide_empty' => false,
);

$terms = get_terms($args);

foreach ($terms as $product_cat) {
  $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta($product_cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
  $image = wp_get_attachment_url($thumbnail_id);
  echo "<img src='" . $image . "'>";
}
```

---

> **This section is related to the plugin used in the question!**

#### UPDATE

Like i said in the comments, the `php` file that you provided is one giant file with "4634" lines of "spaghetti" code with multiple references to other external files. However, on line `1957`, there is a function that seems what we're interested in, and called "get_customized_term_700" and takes in `$term_id`, `$term_slug`, `$term_name`, `$cnt`, `$checked` and `$sublevel`.

In the same function, there is also a `switch` `case` statement. One of the `case` conditions checks for `image`. If there is a filter, it'll output the categories. So we'll use it to output the image.

So go ahead and **REPLACE** the entire function called "get_customized_term_700" on line `1957` with the following function.

**Note:**
This has not been tested, since i don't have access to the plugin, this has been purely written based on the logic in the `php` file. Hope it helps you!

```php
public static function get_customized_term_700($term_id, $term_slug, $term_name, $cnt, $checked = '', $sublevel = '')
  {
    if (!empty($term_id)) {

      $data = array(
        'tooltip' => '',
        'data' => '',
      );

      if (!empty(self::$filter['style']['terms'])) {

        $key = self::__find_customized_term($term_id, self::$filter['style']['terms']);

        if ($key !== false) {
          $data = array_merge(array(
            'tooltip' => '',
            'data' => '',
          ), self::$filter['style']['terms'][$key]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      $data = array(
        'value' => '',
        'title' => self::__get_none_string(),
        'tooltip' => self::__get_none_tooltip_string(),
        'data' => self::__get_customized_term_none(self::$filter['style']['style']['type']),
      );
    }

    if (!empty($data['title'])) {
      $term_name = $data['title'];
    }

    $tip = empty($data['tooltip']) ? false : $data['tooltip'];

    switch (self::$filter['style']['style']['type']) {

      case 'text':
        return '<span class="prdctfltr_customize_' . esc_attr(self::$filter['style']['style']['css']) . ' prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">' . esc_html($term_name) . '</span>' . ($cnt !== false ? ' <span class="prdctfltr_customize_count">' . absint($cnt) . '</span>' : '') . ($tip !== false ? '<span class="prdctfltr_tooltip"><span>' . wp_kses_post($tip) . '</span></span>' : '') . ($checked !== '' ? '<input type="checkbox" value="' . esc_attr($term_slug) . '"' . esc_html($checked) . '/>' : '') . wp_kses_post($sublevel) . '</span>';
        break;

      case 'color':
        if (!empty(self::$filter['style']['label']) && self::$filter['style']['label'] == 'side') {
          return '<span class="prdctfltr_customize_block prdctfltr_customize"' . (!empty(self::$filter['style']['size']) ? sprintf(' style="line-height:%1$spx;', absint(self::$filter['style']['size'])) : '') . '><span class="prdctfltr_customize_color_text"><span style="background-color:' . Prdctfltr()->esc_color($data['data']) . ';' . (!empty(self::$filter['style']['size']) ? sprintf('width:%1$spx;height:%1$spx;', absint(self::$filter['style']['size'])) : '') . '"></span></span>' . ($tip !== false ? '<span class="prdctfltr_tooltip"><span>' . wp_kses_post($tip) . '</span></span>' : '') . ($checked !== '' ? '<input type="checkbox" value="' . esc_attr($term_slug) . '"' . esc_html($checked) . '/>' : '') . '<span class="prdctfltr_customization_search">' . esc_html($term_name) . '</span><span class="prdctfltr_customize_color_text_tip">' . esc_html($term_name) . '</span>' . ($cnt !== false ? ' <span class="prdctfltr_count">' . absint($cnt) . '</span>' : '') . wp_kses_post($sublevel) . '</span>';
        } else {
          return '<span class="prdctfltr_customize_block prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_color" style="background-color:' . Prdctfltr()->esc_color($data['data']) . ';' . (!empty(self::$filter['style']['size']) ? sprintf('width:%1$spx;height:%1$spx;', absint(self::$filter['style']['size'])) : '') . '"></span>' . ($cnt !== false ? ' <span class="prdctfltr_customize_count">' . absint($cnt) . '</span>' : '') . ($tip !== false ? '<span class="prdctfltr_tooltip"><span>' . wp_kses_post($tip) . '</span></span>' : '') . ($checked !== '' ? '<input type="checkbox" value="' . esc_attr($term_slug) . '"' . esc_html($checked) . '/>' : '') . '<span class="prdctfltr_customization_search">' . esc_html($term_name) . '</span>' . wp_kses_post($sublevel) . '</span>';
        }
        break;

      case 'image':
        if (!empty(self::$filter['style']['label']) && self::$filter['style']['label'] == 'side') {
          $args = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'hide_empty' => false,
          );
          $output = '';
          $terms = get_terms($args);
          foreach ($terms as $product_cat) {
            $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta($product_cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url($thumbnail_id);
            $output .= '<span class="prdctfltr_customize_block prdctfltr_customize"' . (!empty(self::$filter['style']['size']) ? sprintf(' style="line-height:%1$spx;"', absint(self::$filter['style']['size'])) : '') . '><span class="prdctfltr_customize_image_text"><img src="' . $image . '"/></span>' . ($tip !== false ? '<span class="prdctfltr_tooltip"><span>' . wp_kses_post($tip) . '</span></span>' : '') . ($checked !== '' ? '<input type="checkbox" value="' . esc_attr($product_cat->slug) . '"' . esc_html($checked) . '/>' : '') . '<span class="prdctfltr_customization_search">' . esc_html($product_cat->name) . '</span><span class="prdctfltr_customize_image_text_tip">' . esc_html($product_cat->name) . '</span>' . ($cnt !== false ? ' <span class="prdctfltr_count">' . absint($cnt) . '</span>' : '') . wp_kses_post($sublevel) . '</span>';
          }
          return $output;
        }
        break;

      case 'select':
        return '<span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize">' . ($checked !== '' ? '<input type="checkbox" value="' . esc_attr($term_slug) . '"' . esc_html($checked) . '/>' : '') . '<span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">' . esc_html($term_name) . '</span>' . ($cnt !== false ? ' <span class="prdctfltr_customize_count">' . absint($cnt) . '</span>' : '') . wp_kses_post($sublevel) . '</span>' . ($tip !== false ? '<span class="prdctfltr_tooltip"><span>' . wp_kses_post($tip) . '</span></span>' : '');
        break;

      case 'html':
        if (!empty($data['data'])) {
          return wp_kses_post(stripslashes($data['data'])) . '<span class="prdctfltr_customization_search">' . esc_html($term_name) . '</span>' . ($tip !== false ? '<span class="prdctfltr_tooltip"><span>' . wp_kses_post($tip) . '</span>' . wp_kses_post($sublevel) . '</span>' : '');
        } else {
          return esc_html($term_name);
        }
        break;

      default:
        return '';
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer Ruvee. I tried to implement your code but it did not help I still do not see thumbnails. It gets me <img src="unknown">. I have updated my question where at the botton you could see the php code. Check the line 2105 where the function is. Maybe I did something wrong there. Thank you for your help! I very appreciate it.

Comment: It's because `$terms` is an array of objects and we need a `foreach` loop to get the data `from each object`. You tried to get the data from the `$terms` and that's why you got <img src="unknown">. I assume you're using the default woocommerce category which is `product_cat` right? Or you're using a custom taxonomy? Also, it'd be great if you could give me the logic of your filter, how you are trying to filter those categories.

Comment: https://potapanie.artbuild.sk/kategoria-produktu/test-kat/ Here is the URL for the filtering. I use normal woocommerce categories yes. You could check it when you open the URL. It works with woocommerce categories only which Ive added from wp admin in woocommerce. What It does not support is thumbnails, you could upload them manually into filter which is a very bad solution. There is probably no custom taxonomy in the filter, it gets everything from woo categories except thumbnails. If you want I may share the plugin files with you.

Comment: In the php file Ive shared with you there is a lot of product_cart calls in it so they also use it. Strange that it does not work with terms.

Comment: Now it loads only one category as you could see on the test URL Ive sent you before and it gets its thumnail. Check it out on the url. We are close but we miss something.

Comment: I see the general category which Ive renamed to akcie. Even it links to the other categories. So we are now getting the general uncategorised woocommerce category as all categories with its thumbnail.

Comment: Now we've got the empty boxes without IMG in html

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: That's to be expected, because i'm shooting in the dark! There are many things that i don't know about your shop and how you've setup your categories and on top of that i don't understand the language of the site and i have to guess which is which! I don't have access to the plugin templates so i don't know how the plugin template calls the function. So, i think that's all i've got for you.

Comment: I can get you an acces if you have a free time to check on it.